# How do I get the files names from FileInfo[]?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
_fi = new DirectoryInfo (subDirectoryName).GetFiles("*.bmp");
label15.Text = _fi.Length.ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < myNumbers.Count; i++)
{
    if (myNumbers[i] >= max_min_threshold)
    {
        FileName = i.ToString("D6") + ".bmp";
        if (File.Exists(subDirectoryName + "\\" + FileName))
           ...
    }
}
```

Now _fi contain 2255 indexes; in each index there is a file name for example in index[0] I see: {000001.bmp}
In index[1] {000002.bmp}

Then I'm running over myNumbers which contain 2256 indexes in each one a number. For example in index[0] there is 225000 in index[1] there is 223000 and so on.

What I want to do is using this loop or some other way and each iteration to get the file name from the _fi variable into FileName variable.

So in the first variable FileName will be 000001.bmp in the second iteration FileName will be 000002.bmp and so on.

The problem is FileName now in the first iteration will be 000000.bmp which does not exist in the hard disk. I see it in _fi the first file is 000001.bmp

So how can I make it work out?

EDITED:

Tried to do this:

```
if (i == _fi.Length)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            FileName = (i + 1).ToString("D6") + ".bmp";
```

The problem is that after the break its going to this part:

```
button5.Enabled = true;
                        myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = counter;
                        myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value = 0;
                        setpicture(0);
```

Now setpicture(0); will show in pictureBox1 the frame/image number 1 which is file: 000001.bmp
This is the setpicture function:

```
private void setpicture(int indx)
        {
            if (_fi == null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Lightnings_Extractor.Properties.Resources.Weather_Michmoret;
                button5.Enabled = false;
                label5.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (indx >= 0 && indx <= myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum && _fi.Length > indx)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        label19.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        fileToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                        label19.Visible = false;
                        label20.Visible = false;
                        label14.Visible = true;
                        label15.Visible = true;
                        label8.Visible = true;
                        label9.Visible = true;
                        myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Enabled = true;
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fi[indx].FullName, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            this.label8.Visible = true;
                            this.label9.Visible = true;
                            this.label9.Text = _fi[indx].Name;
                            Image img = null;
                            Bitmap bmp = null;
                            Image imgOLd = null;

                            try
                            {
                                  
                                img = Image.FromStream(fs);
                                bmp = new Bitmap(img);

                                imgOLd = this.pictureBox1.Image;
                                this.pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                                if (imgOLd != null)
                                    imgOLd.Dispose();

                                img.Dispose();
                                img = null;
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                if (img != null)
                                    img.Dispose();
                                if (bmp != null)
                                    bmp.Dispose();
                                if (imgOLd != null)
                                    imgOLd.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        button1.Enabled = false;
                        label1.Visible = false;
                        label2.Visible = false;
                        label3.Visible = false;
                        label4.Visible = false;
                        label11.Visible = false;
                        label12.Visible = false;
                        checkBox2.Enabled = false;
                        label19.Visible = true;
                        label19.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        label19.Text = "The Selected Directory Is Access Denied";
                        label20.Visible = true;
                        label20.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        label20.Text = "Please Set A Different Directory";
                        fileToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                        label14.Visible = false;
                        label15.Visible = false;
                        label8.Visible = false;
                        label9.Visible = false;
                        myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Enabled = false;
                        timer2.Stop();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Image imgOLd = this.pictureBox1.Image;
                    //this.pictureBox1.Image = null;

                    if (imgOLd != null)
                    {
                        imgOLd.Dispose();
                        imgOLd = null;
                    }
                    
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
        }
```

On the line:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fi[indx].FullName, FileMode.Open))
```

I'm getting exception now which was not before I did the break; if i == _fi.Length but after I did it I'm getting exception on this line its moving to the catch area and throw me:

The process cannot access the file 'D:\New folder (7)\MVI_3041.MOV_Automatic\000001.bmp' because it is being used by another process.

```
System.IO.IOException was caught
  Message=The process cannot access the file 'D:\New folder (7)\MVI_3041.MOV_Automatic\000001.bmp' because it is being used by another process.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
       at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
       at Extracting_Frames.Form1.setpicture(Int32 indx) in D:\C-Sharp\Extracting_Frames\Extracting_Frames\Extracting_Frames\Form1.cs:line 508
  InnerException:
```

I'm not sure why now I'm getting this exception which wasn't before.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get filenames from FileInfo[]:

```
string[] names = new DirectoryInfo(subDirectoryName)
        .GetFiles("*.bmp")
        .Select(fi => fi.Name)
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I know how to get the FileNames but i need to do it in the myNumbers loop. And the myNumbers For should start from 0 since i dont want to miss the first index in myNumbers List. But myNumbers have 2256 indexs and _fi have 2255.

Answer (score 1):

Create the filename like this

```
FileName = (i + 1).ToString("D6") + ".bmp";
```

---

### Update:

In order to access the `FileInfo`s in `_fi`, I would add them to a dictionary in order to allow a fast lookup.

```
Dictionary<string, FileInfo> fileDict = _fi.ToDictionary(f => f.Name);
```

(be sure to have a `using System.Linq;`.)

Then you can look for a file with

```
FileInfo fi;
if (fileDict.TryGetValue(FileName, out fi)) {
    DoSomethingWithTheFile(fi);
}
```

This is much faster than calling `if (File.Exists(...))`

Comment: Not good since its getting in the end to file 002256.bmp and there are only 002255 files in the _fi . I need to get the exact files.

Comment: You must make the difference between the index in the array which will be running from `0` to `N-1` and the "visible" file number which will be running from `1` to `N`. Array indexes are always zero based.

Comment: Oliver im getting error i did this: if (i == _fi.Length)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            FileName = (i + 1).ToString("D6") + ".bmp";
                            Dictionary<string, FileInfo> fileDict = _fi.ToDictionary(f => f.Name);
                            if (fileDict.TryGetValue(FileName, out _fi))             But im getting error on : fileDict.TryGetValue(FileName, out _fi the error say: cannot convert from 'out System.IO.FileInfo[]' to 'out System.IO.FileInfo'

Comment: _fi is FileInfo[] while the TryGetValue is asking for FileInfo and not FileInfo[]

Comment: Make sure that you create this dictionary before the loop (otherwise it would not make sense). `TryGetValue` gives a `FileInfo` not `FileInfo[]`. Use a variable typed as `FileInfo`. In my example I use `FileInfo fi;` which is not the same as `_fi`.

Comment: Tried to change it to this: if (fileDict.TryGetValue(FileName, out _fi[i])) so im not getting errors and its finiding the FileName each time but when its getting to the break; and then to the setpicture function im getting the exception again that it cant access the file 000001.bmp

Comment: Ok moved the Dictionary up like this:  _fi = new DirectoryInfo (subDirectoryName).GetFiles("*.bmp");
                    Dictionary<string, FileInfo> fileDict = _fi.ToDictionary(f => f.Name);
                    And i did : if (fileDict.TryGetValue(FileName, out _fi[i]))  but still same exception Access Deinied on the file.

Comment: If you are getting the same exception as shown above, then obviously the file is still open in an other application or somewhere in the same programm. (Or maybe it has not been closed in a previous (aborted) attempt to run this code.)

Answer (score 0):

Start the for loop at 1 and not 0. That's why it's looking for 000000.bmp first.

EDIT: To do this you'll need to change the array reference.

Comment: i just about said this but if he starts the loop at 1 thats going to skip the first index of his array reference

Comment: Just updated my question after tried something but have another problem with that!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to update printing so that i starts at 1 instead of 0 if you know your first filename is .000001.bmp.  (I'm assuming here that your "D6" override for ToString is just moving the decimal 6 places left from the value of i.

so instead of i.toString("D6") try (i+1).toString("D6").

this is the quick and dirty.  The more 'clean' way would be to start i at 1 in your loops above, but then you would have to alter the array references to not miss the 0 index

Comment: Maybe since i added this break; so the last FileName is locked ? Maybe i need somehow first to release the FileName variable before its doing the setpicture(0);    ?

Comment: I think youre getting that exception because of your if.file.exists check.  It will always be looking at the file (causing it to be in use) when youre trying to load it up later.  I'm not sure how to work around that at the moment though, I'll think on it some.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand your question but if you just want to iterate through the list of files you could just do this...

```
_fi = new DirectoryInfo (subDirectoryName).GetFiles("*.bmp");

foreach (var file in _fi)
{
    FileName = file.Name;

    // The rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: Gene S and what about the loop of the myNumbers ? It will be loop in loop. First the foreach then the For of the myNumbers. I need this myNumbers loop.

Comment: I guess that is the part I was not sure about.  What is the purpose of `myNumbers`?

Comment: myNumbers im checking if its >= the threshold so if i set the threshold max min to 100 so it will show me only specific images on the hard disk and if i set it to 20 so only >= 20 will be show up. Thats why i need the myNumbers since i use a threshold to specific what images to show.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fi[indx].FullName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

Now its working.

Thank you all.